# PHP - GET tag from url

Tags: php, url, tags

I want to get a specific tag from url, from example:

If I have this content:

```
<div id="hey">
   <div id="bla"></div>
</div>

<div id="hey">
   <div id="bla"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to get all divs with the id "hey", ( i think its with preg_match_all ), How can I do that?

- The content inside the tag can be changed.

Comment: @Daniel just a note that `id` values should be unique

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for here.  Are you saying you want to pass in an ID via a query string parameter and then search for that parameter in the page content?  Or are you passing that HTML string via a query parameter and you need to parse that?  Also, your HTML markup is invalid so you'll likely have a tough time programmatically parsing it under any conditions.

Comment: To be clear "from URL", it appears you mean "Given a webpage (whose URL I know) how do I scrape the contents from inside a particular HTML tag?"  As it is, it is hard to tell what is being asked, particularly because "GET" (in all caps) in relation to URLs normally refers to a method of form-data encoding.  (e.g. `http://example.org/?field1=value1` is a URL which could result from a GET form)

Comment: FYI, `id`s are supposed to be single use. If you want to apply styles to multiple elements, you should be defining them to have the same `class`. Having multiple elements with the same ID can cause issues with JavaScript, forms, etc.

Comment: To get url ( for example $url ) and to print only the content inside the divs which I want to print ( like "hey").

Answer (score 3):

I recommend use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class instead of regular expressions (is less resource consumer and more clear IMHO).

```
$content = '<div id="hey">
   <div id="bla"></div>
</div>

<div id="hey">
   <div id="bla"></div>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($content); // @ for possible not standard HTML
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='hey']");

/*@var $elements DOMNodeList */
for ($i=0;$i<$elements->length;$i++) {
    /*@var $curr_element DOMElement */
    $curr_element = $elements->item($i);

    // Here do what you want with the element
    var_dump($curr_element);
}
```

If you want to get the content from an URL you can use this line instead to fill the variable $content:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://yourserver/urls/page.php');
```

Comment: You should probably also suppress errors on the `loadHTML()` call, otherwise the DOMDocument will complain loudly about the multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: @AgentConundrum, I test with the HTML with same ids and surprisingly none problems arise, but just in case I add the @ to that line.

Comment: What are your error reporting settings? It issues an `E_WARNING` for me: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: ID hey already defined in Entity, line: 5`

Comment: I set as the initial line `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and nothing appears. I will check again.